# jqGrid: Sending param with dataUrl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jqgrid

I'm trying to create a dependent dropdown box. 'element' is dependent on 'grouping'.

My ajaxSelectOptions function seems to work, as 'temp' is passed, but then it isn't used by 'populate_element'. How can I use the 'temp' as my parameter :id?

My grid:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var lastsel;
var grid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

url:'codes/get_data.xml',
datatype: 'xml',
mtype: 'GET',
colNames:['ID', 'Version', 'Grouping', 'Element', 'Name'],
colModel:[
    {name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true, editable: false },
    {name: 'version', index: 'version',editable: true, editrules:{number:true}, cellEdit: true, search:true },
    {name: 'grouping', index: 'grouping', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {dataUrl: 'codes/populate_grouping.html'} },
    {name: 'element', index: 'element', editable: true, edittype: 'select' }
],
pager: '#pager',
rowNum:200,
rowList:[50,100,200],
sortname: 'id',
sortorder: 'asc',
viewrecords: true, 
height: 500,
scrollrows: true,
rownumbers: false,
caption: 'GL Codes',
editurl: 'codes/post_data.xml',

onSelectRow: function(id){
    $("#list").setColProp('element', {editoptions: { dataUrl: 'codes/populate_element.html' }});

    if(id && id!==lastsel){
        $('#list').restoreRow(lastsel);         
       lastsel=id;
    }
    $('#list').editRow(id,true);        
},
ajaxSelectOptions: {
      data: {
        temp: function(temp){
          return grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')
        } 
      }
    }

});
```

Here is my error message:

```
Started GET "/codes/populate_element.html?temp=4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-27 17:18:33 +1200
Processing by CodesController#populate_element as HTML
  Parameters: {"temp"=>"4"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Code without an ID):
app/controllers/codes_controller.rb:73:in `populate_element'
```

**Update**
I established that it was actually just a ruby syntax error in calling the param, rather than a jqGrid problem. For reference, I ended up calling it like so ... @code = Code.where(["id = ?",params[:temp]]).first

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you use wrong ids for the rows of grid. The error exist during *filling* of the grid. The most easy way to fix the problem will be to add `key: true` property to the definition of the `'id'` column in `colModel`. In the case the value from the column `id` will be used as the rowid: the value of `id` attribute of rows (`<tr>`) of the grid.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My row id is specified in the xml file that the grid gets the data from ( <row id='<%=code.id%>' > ), but I've specified it in colModel too now to be extra sure. I've updated with my solution. Thanks for your time :)